# Trending Topics / Trending Docs On Firestore

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an application with angular and firestore and I have come to the need to process the data to obtain the most used documents.

The only way I can think of is to create a function when a document is read, and increase the counter. But I think that way is very rudimentary.

I wonder if you could you recommend some development paradigm for trending topics, maybe machine learning, or big data.

I do not know where to start, I do not ask you to give me the answer, only  recommend a path to follow to provide the trending documents to my application.